# ng-include Won't Work Without <Body> Tags

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I am starting to get to grips with a lot of the angularjs tutorials out on the net and I seem to have stubbled upon something that my googlefu cant seem to crack.

Below is my html. In my app.js I simply instantiate the angular module and declare `'ui-router'` as a dependancy, nothing flash.

```
<body id="home">

<!-- INIT: app -->
<div class="container" ng-app="app">

    <!-- GET: Header partial -->
    <div ng-include src="'templates/header.html'"></div>

    <!-- INIT: Angular-ui-router -->
    <div ui-view>

    </div>

    <!-- GET: Footer partial -->
    <div ng-include src="'templates/footer.html'"></div>
</div>

<!-- GET: Various Vendor JS files -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendorjs/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendorjs/angular.js"></script>
<script src="vendorjs/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

<!-- GET: My own app JS files -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>

</body>
```

Now for some reason, the files that are included using `ng-include` need to have `<body></body>` tags wrapped around their content or nothing is displayed.

I haven't seen this mentioned anywhere so is there something awry here as I'm totally lost. The current work around is fine but It feels funky.

NOTE: I am using live-server package from `npm live-server` to have my local file refresh in the browser on save. I don't think this is the issue as even if I simply just open the index.html file it still doesn't work (but that's because of chrome's safety rules).

Cheers!

Comment: I get the same problem a weeks ago, and solve with that
<div ng-include src="views/sidepanel.html"></div>

Comment: How is this different to mine? I tried using just a set of quotation marks but still no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, had the same problem with ng-include and Live-Server not loading the partial. ng-include displays the partial in my localhost but not live-server.

This issue has been fixed in the latest version of live-server. So I updated my live-server to version 0.7.1 and ng-include now works just fine.

GitHub - tapio commented 15 days ago
"I've published version 0.7.1 to npm which seems to fix this issue. Feel free to test and report any further problems. :)"
[GitHub live-server issue](https://github.com/tapio/live-server/issues/27)

Comment: Wow, thanks for this! I'll have to check it out. Cheers for helping me out!